# "multipart config was not present on Servlet" when trying to upload a file with JAX-RS class

Tags: file-upload, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following JAX-RS class to upload a file from a browser (implemented in Wildfly 14). Problem is I get the error `multipart config was not present on Servlet`. Since I annotated the class with `@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })` I'm not sure what is missing. How to fix this problem?

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public class FileUploadService {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    public Response processUpload() throws IOException, ServletException {

        String path = "/mypath";    

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {

            String fileName = getFileName(part);
            String fullPath = path + File.separator +  fileName;

            // delete file if exists
            java.nio.file.Path path2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(fullPath);
            Files.deleteIfExists(path2);

            // get file input stream
            InputStream fileContent = part.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileContent.available()];
            fileContent.read(buffer);
            File targetFile = new File(fullPath);

            // write output file
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            outStream.write(buffer);
            outStream.close();
        }

        return Response.ok("OK").build();
    }


    private String getFileName(Part part) {
        for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (content.trim().startsWith("filename"))
                return content.substring(content.indexOf("=") + 2, content.length() - 1);
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```