# Implementation agnostic way to consume Multipart/Form-Data in JAX-RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, multipartform-data

So lets say i got many methods jersey dependent

```
@POST
@Path("stage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ContractStageFile replaceFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition)  throws FileFacade.TransactionRepositoryException {
...
}
```

Then one day we started migration to Wildfly. Well i had to rewrite all those methods using Resteasy  multipart implementation.

```
@POST
@Path("stage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ContractStageFile replaceFile(@MultiPartForm Form form)  throws FileFacade.TransactionRepositoryException {
...
}
```

I thought that there should be a way to do better without unnecessary dependencies.
So i tried to obtain Part from Servlet directly like so

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String upload(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException, ServletException {
    servletContext.setAttribute(MultipartConfig.class.getName(),new MultipartConfigElement("C:\\deleteme\\tmp"));
    Part file = request.getPart("file");
    return 'upload';
}
```

But i got an error “multipart config was not present on Servlet” [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451988/multipart-config-was-not-present-on-servlet-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-with/62189851#62189851)

So is there a Implementation agnostic way to consume File with mime "Multipart/Form-Data"?

Comment: Try to add the `multipart-config` in your web.xml

Comment: how am i supposed to configure Multipart Config Globally? Web.xml doesnt seem to accept tag <MultipartConfig> at root level?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
</web-app>`

Comment: Annotation `@MultipartConfig` seems to be ignored... adding `@Webservlet` and extending `HttpServlet` didn't solve the problem. @paul-samsotha is there another way perhaps?